# Template deduction for function based on its return type?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I'd like to be able to use template deduction to achieve the following:

```
GCPtr<A> ptr1 = GC::Allocate();
GCPtr<B> ptr2 = GC::Allocate();
```

instead of (what I currently have):

```
GCPtr<A> ptr1 = GC::Allocate<A>();
GCPtr<B> ptr2 = GC::Allocate<B>();
```

My current Allocate function looks like this:

```
class GC
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    static GCPtr<T> Allocate();
};
```

Would this be possible to knock off the extra `<A>` and `<B>`?

Comment: fwiw I had something similar but with a return type based on constructor arguments' types. i made a templated helper function `make_complex_template_obj(the, args)`, so I can use `auto` when init'ing  variables from that func. presumably for the same reason as  in the accepted answer, that template couldn't be given `auto` return type. thankfully i could avoid duplicating the typename in the `return` as by then it knew what type was coming and converted a bare _initialiser-list_ appropriately. quite an adventure!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That cannot be done. The return type does not take part in type deduction, it is rather a result of having already matched the appropriate template signature. You can, nevertheless, hide it from most uses as:

```
// helper
template <typename T>
void Allocate( GCPtr<T>& p ) {
   p = GC::Allocate<T>();
}

int main()
{
   GCPtr<A> p = 0;
   Allocate(p);
}
```

Whether that syntax is actually any better or worse than the initial `GCPtr<A> p = GC::Allocate<A>()` is another question.

P.S. c++11 will allow you to skip one of the type declarations:

```
auto p = GC::Allocate<A>();   // p is of type GCPtr<A>
```

Answer (score 36):

The only thing I can think of: make Allocate a non-template that returns a non-template proxy object that has a templated conversion operator which does the real work:

```
template <class T>
struct GCPtr
{

};

class Allocator
{
public:
    template <class T>
    operator GCPtr<T>() { return GCPtr<T>(); }
};

class GC
{
public:
    static Allocator Allocate() { return Allocator(); }//could give a call-back pointer?
};

int main()
{
    GCPtr<int> p = GC::Allocate();
}
```

Comment: It seems overkill, but still, I did not know this pattern. You taught me something. So +1.

Comment: Anyway, at first glance, I guess you could avoid the GC::Allocate() altogether and write : `GCPtr<int> p = Allocator() ;` , no ?

Comment: As the comment says, the Allocator object could store additional data that it receives through the constructor, so GC::Allocate can decide what data it needs for the operation. - Eventually the constructor of `GCPtr<T>` could do the work itself (invoke `GC::Allocate<T>`).

Comment: Is there a way to pass an argument to Allocator? Something like https://godbolt.org/z/nScp8c

Answer (score 8):

You could go the opposite route.

If you're using an up to date compiler (MSVC 2010 which should be out in a couple of days, or the current version of GCC) and don't mind relying on C++0x features:

```
auto ptr1 = GC::Allocate<A>();
auto ptr2 = GC::Allocate<B>();
```

would save you the extra `<A>` and `<B>`, just not on the right hand side. :)

Answer (score 4):

(This answer is the same as @UncleBens, but a bit more general as it perfect-forward any arguments.)

This is very useful in languages like haskell where, for example, [`read`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aread) will take a string as input and will parse it according to the desired return type.

(Here is [sample code on ideone](http://ideone.com/9w3Dzu).)

First, start with the function `foo` whose return type we wish to deduce:

```
template<typename Ret>
Ret foo(const char *,int);
template<>
std::string foo<std::string>(const char *s,int) { return s; }
template<>
int         foo<int        >(const char *,int i) { return i; }
```

When asked for a string, it'll return the string that's in its first argument.  When asked for an int, it'll return the second argument.

We can define a function `auto_foo` that can be used as follows:

```
int main() {
        std::string s = auto_foo("hi",5); std::cout << s << std::endl;
        int         i = auto_foo("hi",5); std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

---

To make this work, we need an object that will temporarily store the function arguments, and also run the function when it is asked to [convert](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/advanced-c-conversion-operators/) to the desired return type:

```
#include<tuple>

template<size_t num_args, typename ...T>
class Foo;
template<typename ...T>
class Foo<2,T...> : public std::tuple<T&&...>
{
public: 
        Foo(T&&... args) :
                std::tuple<T&&...>(std::forward<T>(args)...)
        {}
        template< typename Return >
        operator Return() { return foo<Return>(std::get<0>(*this), std::get<1>(*this)); }
};
template<typename ...T>
class Foo<3,T...> : std::tuple<T&&...>
{
public: 
        Foo(T&&... args) :
                std::tuple<T&&...>(std::forward<T>(args)...)
        {}
        template< typename Return >
        operator Return() { return foo<Return>(std::get<0>(*this), std::get<1>(*this), std::get<2>(*this)); }
};

template<typename ...T>
auto
auto_foo(T&&... args)
        // -> Foo<T&&...> // old, incorrect, code
        -> Foo< sizeof...(T), T&&...> // to count the arguments
{
        return              {std::forward<T>(args)...};
}
```

Also, the above works for two-arg or three-arg functions, it's not difficult to see how to extend that.

This is a lot of code to write!  For each function you will to apply this to, you could write a macro that does this for you.  Something like this at the top of your file:

```
REGISTER_FUNCTION_FOR_DEDUCED_RETURN_TYPE(foo); // declares
                        // necessary structure and auto_???
```

and then you could use `auto_foo` in your program.

Comment: I find it quite interesting, but I believe you are missing the specialization parameter in auto_foo :
`auto auto_foo(T&&... args) -> Foo<sizeof...(T), T&&...>`, because otherwise it won't select the specialization IMHO.

Comment: You're right. I'll update the code here. I had tested the code on my computer, but obviously I didn't copy it exactly. Thanks!

Comment: In any case it's a nice way to implement this. Thanks for the example.

Comment: Interesting solution, is there a reason why you've choosen std::tuple_size instead of directly using sizeof...(T) ?

Comment: No reason, @daminetreg . I've changed it now. I had simply copied and pasted it from my working example, and I don't know how I wrote it that way in the first place! (*Update: I may have tried `sizeof(T)...` first, thinking that `...` always goes on the end of the expression in which expansion should occur. But that doesn't work that way, so perhaps that's why I went for `tuple_size` instead*)

Comment: Is it necessary for function `foo` to have parameters `(const char *,int)`? If I want the same feature for function `template <typename _Ty, int N> SquareMatrix<_Ty, N> MakeIdentityMatrix()`, which asks for no input at all?

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you can't overload functions on return type, you can't do template deduction on it. And for the same reason - if f() is a template/overload that returns something, what type to use here:

```
f();
```

Comment: Well I've thought about that already. My garbage collector class uses reference counting, and calling GC::Allocate() will inherently have 0 references which would just get cleaned up anyway. This is of course if the code compiled/

Comment: Compiler error, unless appearing in a cast (`(int)f();`) ...?

Comment: @UncleBens: nice idea! However, the C++ compiler doesn't currently work this way.

Comment: @Neil, what I was trying to say was I have already thought about what happens when f() is called by itself (a compile error). Now replace f() with GC::Allocate() and imagine it did compile. My garbage collector uses reference counting and since the return value is not stored in a GCPtr the reference count is at 0 and the garbage collector would just clean it up instantly. This is all hypothetical since the code doesnt actually compile.

Comment: @Neil: I mean, this is how overloading and type deduction based on return type could *hypothetically* work if it existed.

Comment: @UncleBens Oh well, hypothetically... I don't think that would be sufficient reason to reintroduce C-style casts though. And it would make overloaded functions work differently from non-overloaded ones, WRT the return type.

Comment: @Neil: You could use a `static_cast` too. I don't think the mechanism would be too different from disambiguating between overloads by casting arguments (or selecting which conversion operator to invoke). Inconvenient to use it happily everywhere, but nice to have if you need it.

Comment: @UncleBens But what if you do actually want to cast the return value?

Comment: @Neil: Good point. `int foo(); long foo(); static_cast<double>(foo());` -> ambiguous overloads. Workaround: `long l = foo(); static_cast<double>(l);`, or `static_cast<double>(static_cast<long>(foo());`

Comment: @Neil: Then you would have to do two nested casts. Not nice, but there's cases we have to do that now. Note that Ada has had overloading based on return type for decades. (It's not like I'm desperately missing it in C++, it's just that it, in principle,  is a possible feature.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a macro for it. Other than that, I don't see how that's supposed to work with just one statement.

```
#define ALLOC(ptrname,type) GCPtr<type> ptrname = GC::Allocate<type>()

ALLOC(ptr1,A);
```

Johannes' points are valid. The >> issue is easily fixed. But I think having commas as part of the type requires the C99 preprocessor varargs extension:

```
#define ALLOC(ptrname,...) GCPtr< __VA_ARGS__ > ptrname = GC::Allocate< __VA_ARGS__ >()

ALLOC(ptr1,SomeTemplate<int,short>);
```

Comment: Notice that this macro fails if you do `ALLOC(ptr1, A<a, b>);` (there are two problems: No space after `type` (aka' `>>`) and the comma makes two macro arguments out of `A<a, b>`).

Comment: And what would that buy you? You'd still have to mention the type, and it's less safe than David's solution with an inlined function template. -1 from me.

Comment: You can solve both problems by saying `ALLOC(ptr1, (A<a, b>));` and rewriting the macro to pass a function-type to `template<typename T> struct ty; template<typename Ty> struct ty<void(Ty)> { typedef Ty type; };` and say `GCPtr<ty<void type>::type> ptrname` instead (and the same with `typename` for use within templates. C++0x and some current c++03 compilers allows `typename` also outside of templates, though).

Comment: @sbi: Sure, I wouldn't use such a macro in my code. That that was the only thing that came to my mind. And of course you have to name the type at least once even with Davids solution.

Comment: @ltb: that's mighty clever to work around C99 varargs macros. But it does have the problem that you need two versions if the type depends on template arguments.