# Generic container for multiple data types in C++

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, containers

Using C++, I'm trying to create a generic container class to handle multiple data types.  It's a common problem with a variety of solutions, but I've found nothing as... intuitive as I've grown accustomed to in languages like Python or even VB/VBA...

So here's my scenario:

I've built a DataContainer class based on boost::any which I use to store multiple data types of multiple elements.  I use a map declared as:

```
std::map<std::string, DataContainer* (or DataContainerBase*)>
```

where DataContainer is a class that encapsulates an object of the type:

```
std::list<boost::any>
```

along with convenience functions for managing / accessing the list.

However, in the end, I'm still forced to do type conversions outside the data container.

For example, if I were to store a list of int values in the map, accessing them would require:

```
int value = boost::any_cast<int>(map["myValue"]->get());
```

I'd rather the boost code be contained entirely within the data container structure, so I would only need type:

```
int value = map["myValue"]->get();
```

or, worst-case:

```
int value = map["myValue"]->get<int>();
```

Of course, I could enumerate my data types and do something like:

```
int value = map["myValue"]->get( TYPE_INT );
```

or write type-specific get() functions:

```
getInt(), getString(), getBool() ...
```

The problem with the last two options is that they are somewhat inflexible, requiring me to declare explicitly each type I wish to store in the container.  The any_cast solution (which I have implemented and works) I suppose is fine, it's just... inelegant?  I dunno.  It seems I shouldn't need to employ the internal mechanics externally as well.

As I see it, passing the value without declaring the value type in the call to the DataContainer member function would require a void* solution (which is undesirable for obvious reasons), and using a "get()" call would require (so far as I can tell) a "virtual template" member function defined at the base class level, which, of course, isn't allowed.

As it is, I have a workable solution, and really, my use in this case is limited enough in scope that most any solutions will work well.  But I am wondering if perhaps there's a more flexible way to manage a generic, multi-type data container than this.

Comment: Have a look on `boost::variant` too, maybe (?) this is what you're looking for.

Comment: What's wrong with just a `std::map<std::string, boost::any>`?

Comment: Also, since your `DataContainer` is under your control, why not just add a member function `template <typename T> get_as() { return boost::any_cast<T>(get()); }` to wrap the any-cast? Then you can say `m["abc"]->get_as<int>()`, as you suggested. Sounds simple enough.

Comment: Haven't looked at `boost::variant` (though I noticed it).  So far as a straight map goes, I'm tokenizing user input that may include vectors.  Technically, the entire vector is, itself, a complete token when I'm validating the input (the `DataContainer` provides that degree of atomicity), but I want the individual elements to be separate as well, hence the `std::list`.  Otherwise, any other token (scalar numeric, or word), would create a one-element list, which would be the same as a `map<string, boost::any>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to introduce some sugar for this:

```
int value = boost::any_cast<int>(map["myValue"]->get());
```

then you might want to make the `get()` function to return a proxy object, defined +- like this:

```
struct Proxy {
    boost::any& value;
    Proxy(boost::any& value) : value(value) {}

    template<typename T>
    operator T() {
        return boost::any_cast<T>(value);
    }
};
```

Then this syntax would work:

```
int value = map["myValue"]->get();
// returns a proxy which gets converted by any_cast<int>
```

However I recommend to keep things explicit and just use that syntax:

```
int value = map["myValue"]->get<int>();
```

Here `get` doesn't return a proxy object with a template method, but is a template method itself (but does the same as the template conversion operator shown above).

Comment: @JoelGraff If i am not off by to much you might even get away with just `get()` in the second case thanks to automatic template parameter deduction.
you might consider to store the DataCOntainer directly to save one level of indirection. A list instant itself shoudl be pretty small (only the head), the elements are on the heap anyway.

Comment: I believe auto parameter deduction only works for the parameters, not the return type.

Comment: you are right, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2612979/258418, it also points out ways to leave out one type through workarounds, however this is only interesting for rather complex types

Comment: Yah, UncleBens' solution looks the same as what I've mentioned here.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Frankly, I prefer to be explicit, but verbosity gets hard to manage, so it's a constant battle for me to strike the balance... But I think a get<T>() solution is probably best.

Answer (score 1):

Today I have done some source code for the purpose you want. I know that this question is so old, but maybe this little piece of code is helpful for someone. It is mainly based on boost:any.

```
/*
 * AnyValueMap.hpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jun 3, 2013
 *      Author: alvaro
 */

#ifndef ANYVALUEMAP_HPP_
#define ANYVALUEMAP_HPP_

#include <map>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class AnyValueMap {

public:
    AnyValueMap(){}

    virtual ~AnyValueMap(){}

private:
    map<T, boost::any> container_;

    typedef typename map<T, boost::any>::iterator map_iterator;
    typedef typename map<T, boost::any>::const_iterator map_const_iterator;

public:

    bool containsKey(const T key) const
    {
        return container_.find(key) != container_.end();
    }

    bool remove(const T key)
    {
        map_iterator it = container_.find(key);
        if(it != container_.end())
        {
            container_.erase(it);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    template <class V>
    V getValue(const T key, const V defaultValue) const
    {
        map_const_iterator it = container_.find(key);
        if(it != container_.end())
        {
            return boost::any_cast<V>(it->second);
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }

    template <class V>
    V getValue(const T key) const
    {
        return boost::any_cast<V>(container_.at(key));
    }

    template <class V>
    void setValue(const T key, const V value)
    {
        container_[key] = value;
    }
};

#endif /* ANYVALUEMAP_HPP_ */
```

A simple usage example:

```
AnyValueMap<unsigned long> myMap;
myMap.setValue<double>(365, 1254.33);
myMap.setValue<int>(366, 55);
double storedDoubleValue = myMap.getValue<double>(365);
int storedIntValue = myMap.getValue<int>(366);
```