# Why does not C++ compiler convert template function arguments to match expected result type?

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Template deduction for function based on its return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612961/template-deduction-for-function-based-on-its-return-type)

I am trying to figure out how C++ templates work. As an example, I want to write a simple data structure, `triple` which behaves like STL's `pair` but has three items. Of course, I want to implement it using templates. And I am facing a strange behaviour from my point of view.

First, I have a working example. Here is the C++ code that works:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
T1 getSum(T1 a1, T2 a2) {
    return a1 + a2;
}

int main(int argc, int *argv[]) {
    long l1 = 1, l2 = 0, l3 = 0, l4 =0;
    short s1 = 2, s2 = 0, s3 = 0, s4 = 0;
    l2 = getSum(l1, s1);
    l3 = getSum(s1, l1);
    l4 = getSum(1, 2);
    s2 = getSum(l1, s1);
    s3 = getSum(s1, l1);
    s4 = getSum(1, 2);
    cout << l2 << " " << l3 << " " << l4 << endl;
    cout << s2 << " " << s3 << " " << s4 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result of this program is two lines containing `3 3 3` each. Since I call `getSum` function with various combination of arguments: `(long, short)`, `(short, long)` and `(integer literal, integer literal)` and the return value is assigned into both `long` and `short` variables each time, I assume that compiler knows how to make an appropriate conversion or *guessing of types* by return values (in case of integer literals) each time.

And here we come back to simple `triple` implementation. I do everything in pretty the same way (as it seems to me) but I get a conversion error. Here is what I mean. My code looks like the following:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct triple {
    T1 first;
    T2 second;
    T3 third;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
triple<T1, T2, T3> mt(T1 f, T2 s, T3 t) {
    triple<T1, T2, T3> tr;
    tr.first = f;
    tr.second = s;
    tr.third = t;
    return tr;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    triple<char, char, unsigned short> t = mt(0, 0, 65000);
    cout << t.first << " " << t.second << " " << t.third << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
22: error: conversion from 'triple<int, int, int>' to non-scalar type
'triple<char, char, short unsigned int>' requested
```

(22nd line is the first line of `main` function).

It is not surprise that conversion between two aforementioned `triple`s is not a compiler's business. But it is a surprise for me that compiler *cannot determine* that since I want to get `triple<char, char, short unsigned int>` as a result of `mt` function, template arguments should be determined as `T1 == char`, `T2 == char`, `T3 == unsigned short`.

And since things work this way now, I'm confused about how `make_pair` function works. Its [code](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/make_pair/) looks very alike to mine (again, as it seems to me).

So, my question is: please, clarify the essential differences between my code and working one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your case is that your function `mt` has a fixed return type already: `Triple<int, int, int>` (determined by the parameters, and integer constants are always considered to be `int` unless specified otherwise). Once created that way, it can't be assigned, since it's a different type, and there is no type conversion or constructor defined which would allow what you're trying to do.

At the moment, there's no constructor at all explicitly defined in your `triple` strucht - which means there's only default constructor and the copy constructor (which works only for the exact same type)!

But there is a solution:Take a look at the [definition of pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/): See the copy constructor (which is templated *again*, in addition to the template parameters on the base class). To make it work for your case, add your own templated copy constructor:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct triple {
    template <typename U1, typename U2, typename U3>    
    triple(U1 f, U2 s, U3 t):
        first(f),
        second(s),
        third(t) {}
    T1 first;
    T2 second;
    T3 third;
};
```

Instead of using a function returning a triple, you could also simply use another constructor taking the three parameters:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct triple {
    triple(T1 f, T2 s, T3 t):
        first(f),
        second(s),
        third(t) {}
    T1 first;
    T2 second;
    T3 third;
};
```

and then in main you could write:

```
triple<char, char, unsigned short> t(0, 0, 65000);
```

It's also less to write!

Comment: Thanks, I get that. But that is another way to do what I want to do. And I would like to know why my way does not work – just to understand how templating system is organized.

Comment: updated my answer - hope it's clear now

Answer (score 4):

In general, C++ does not infer a return type based on how that type is used. Rather, it infers the return type from what you tell it the return type is.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
T1 getSum(T1 a1, T2 a2)
```

Here, the code says that the return type is the same type as the first argument, `T1`. The thing with arithmetic types is that there are implicit conversions between them, so all of the assignment statements in the code work, either because the return type is the same as the type being assigned to, or because the return type can be converted to the type being assigned to.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
triple<T1, T2, T3> mt(T1 f, T2 s, T3 t)
```

Here, the code tells the compiler that the return type is a `triple` whose three elements have the same types as the three arguments to the function. The call `mt(0, 0, 65000)` has three arguments of type int, so the return type is `triple<int, int, int>`.

Answer (score 2):

To provide some clarification on the compiler error, the reason it does not occur with `std::pair` and `make_pair` is that `std::pair` has a template constructor that accepts `std::pair` of any type.

Changing to the following code will mirror `std::pair` much more and resolve the compiler error:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct triple {
    T1 first;
    T2 second;
    T3 third;

    triple() {}

    template <typename U1, typename U2, typename U3>
    triple(const triple<U1, U2, U3>& rhs)
      : first(rhs.first),
        second(rhs.second),
        third(rhs.third)
    {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it works for `std::pair` is not due to the functionality of `std::make_pair`, but instead is due to one of the extra constructors `std::pair` has.

Looking at [the list of pair constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair), you will find that #4 is

```
template< class U1, class U2 >
pair( const pair<U1,U2>& p );
```

This allows `std::pair` to be initialized from any other pair, as long as U1 is convertible to T1, and U2 is convertible to T2.

To make it work with your triple, you would have to add the same sort of constructors/assignment operators.  Note, `std::tuple` or `boost::tuple` already provide that functionality if they are available to you.