# How can I use a non-template proxy object that has a template conversion operator to avoid specifying the type of my boost::variant?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I have the following variant:

```
typedef boost::variant<double, long int, std::string> ConfigVariant;
```

I then define a map:

```
std::map<std::string, ConfigVariant> config_values;
```

I also have this `operator[]` in my Config class (Config contains both the variant and the map):

```
ConfigVariant & Config::operator[] (const string &key) {
  return config_values[key];
}
```

Ideally, I would like to say `double d = config_values["double_key"]` instead of `double d = boost::get<double>(config_values["double_key"])`. According to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613010/887128), it should be possible to use a non-template proxy with a template conversion operator to do what I want, but I am unsure of how. Can someone provide some guidance? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some detail to be able to answer properly; i.e. you don't say anything about `Config` apart from the `operator[]` member.

Perhaps implement `Config::operator[]` as a template to call `boost::get<>`, so instead of

```
ConfigVariant & Config::operator[] (const string &key) {
    return config_values[key];
}
```

you have:

```
template<typename T>
T &Config::operator[] (const string &key) {
    return boost::get<T>(config_values["double_key"]);
}
```

Now you can write

```
double d = config["double_key"];
```

Assuming `config` is of type `Config`