# Error in using template for function

Tags: c++, templates, types

I want to create a function that returns different types of data-types for different input string. I am using templates for it but seems like I am making some mistake.

```
template<typename S>
S select(string type){

int integer;
float floaty;
char character;
string strings;

if(type=="int")
    return integer;

if(type=="char")
    return character;

if(type=="float")
    return floaty;

if(type=="string")
    return strings;
}
```

it gives this error when I run it will string argument int .

```
    sam.cpp:771:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘select(std::string&)’
  select(type);
             ^
sam.cpp:771:13: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:219:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:314,
                 from Markup.h:12,
                 from sam.cpp:3:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/select.h:106:12: note: int select(int, fd_set*, fd_set*, fd_set*, timeval*)
 extern int select (int __nfds, fd_set *__restrict __readfds,
            ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/select.h:106:12: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 1 provided
sam.cpp:17:3: note: template<class S> S select(std::string)
 S select(string type){
   ^
sam.cpp:17:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
sam.cpp:771:13: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘S’
  select(type);
```

If it is wrong way and there is a better way of doing things then do share, Thanks.

Comment: You haven't shown the call site, where the error is...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Template deduction for function based on its return type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612961/template-deduction-for-function-based-on-its-return-type)

Answer (score 3):

In C++ template type deduction is based on parameter and not on return type so, in your particular case, when you are calling the function select, you have to explicitly specify the template argument.

> then how will I achieve what I want to do with this function?

Use template specialization.

```
template<typename S>
S select(){
static_assert("Not Implemented");
}

template<> int select<int>() {
    int integer;
    //To Do
    return integer;
}

template<> float select<float >() {
    float floaty;
    //To Do
    return floaty;
}
//Remaining Specialization
```

and call the respective specialization using explicit template parameter

```
int main()
{
    int _integer = select<int>();
    float _float = select<float>();
    ..........
}
```

Comment: then how will I achieve what I want to do with this function?

Comment: @Bramsh You won't. C++ is statically typed, while you want the return type of `select` to depend on a runtime value (the content of `type`). Look into something like [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: @Angew: Though the question was not well framed, but what he wants to achieve can easily be done through template specialization.

Comment: @Abhijit How? The solution you've presented doesn't use the OP's `type` parameter at all.

Comment: @Angew: Doesn't need to, but if you see closely, it solves OPs problem. As I mentioned, the question is not clearly worded, but template specialization would solve the problem. How I am seeing OPs question is a X-Y problem as he lacks knowledge on template concepts. Please let me know if you still disagree.

Comment: @Abhijit thanks for help, but I want it to work like this in main :  suppose I have an array of strings str, I don't know what it holds, I am actually overloading functions on the basis of one different parameter.  void func(-,-, select(str[0]));  // now i have 4 functions that are overloaded on the basis of their last different parameter, one has int other float, other string and last one char. so this select function will help me to call overloaded functions. as I won't know values of str array so I can't just call them on my own. I need generic way. Any way for it?

Comment: @Bramsh: The important thing to note is, if you know and can decide on the type during compile time using static polymorphism (templates), if the type is not known until runtime, use dynamic polymorphism (virtual functions, RTTI (dynamic cast))

Comment: @Abhijit But virtual functions only exist in classes I guess, and I am not using them. well, I will think about using them. And thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way this can work. Templates require their parameters to be known at compile time, but the value of `type` is only known at run time.

If `S` is `int` then `return strings` won't compile, but if `S` is `string` then `return integer` won't compile.

And as others have pointed out `S` cannot be deduced, so you have to specify it explicitly in the call. But it still can't work for the reason above.

(Quite apart from all that, you haven't initialised any of the values.)