# How I correctly write a inline template function to advance a pointer by an offset and return the pointer to another type?

Tags: c++, templates

### Ask

How can I assign a pointer to an object type to a pointer to another by `template<typename To, typename From> To* offsetptr(From *p, size_t off)` without no template argument in c++?

### Desciption

As we all know, when increasing or decreasing a pointer, the difference value is the size of the object pointed to by the pointer.
In order to add a specific offset to a pointer, I think that there are two manners:

1. Convert to a pointer to `char` -> Pointer arithmetic -> Cast back or cast to a pointer to another type.
2. Cast to intptr_t that has enough bits to accommodate a pointer -> Integer arithmetic -> Cast back or cast to a pointer to another type.

In c++, it's not allowed to directly assign pointers to object types converted to pointers to another(e.g. `int *pint1 = raw.a` gcc gives `error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'int*' in initialization`) and need a explicit type-cast.

So, I want to expect a template to help me, but it seems that a template argument as a return type cannot be deduced correctly from the type of lvalue in assigment expression and must (See the following codes).

```
template<typename To, typename From> To convert(From f);

void g(double d) 
{
    int i = convert<int>(d);    // calls convert<int, double>(double)
    char c = convert<char>(d);  // calls convert<char, double>(double)
    int(*ptr)(float) = convert; // instantiates convert<int, float>(float)
}
```

My test [code](http://ideone.com/ZWA5Ym) using c++14 or `g++.exe -Wall -std=c++11`

```
// int i = 6; offsetptr(i, 16) == 22
// int *i = offsetptr(pchar, 16); *i == 22
template<typename DstPointeeType, typename SrcPointeeType> 
inline static DstPointeeType* offsetptr(SrcPointeeType *p, size_t off) {
  cout << "p = " << p << ", *p = " << *p << endl;
  return reinterpret_cast<DstPointeeType*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p)  + off);
}

template<typename DstType, typename SrcType> 
inline static DstType differby(SrcType src, size_t off) {
  return reinterpret_cast<DstType>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(src)  + off);
}

template<typename DstType, typename SrcType> 
inline static DstType udifferby(SrcType src, size_t off) {
  return reinterpret_cast<DstType>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(src)  + off);
}

template<> int* offsetptr<int, char>(char *p, size_t off) {
  cout << "p = " << p << ", *p = " << *p << endl;
  return reinterpret_cast<int*>(p  + off);
}

//template<typename InType, typename OutType> static const OutType* offsetptr(const InType *p,
//      size_t off) {
//  return (const OutType*) ((const char*) p + off);
//}


template<typename T> inline static void moveptr(T **pp, unsigned int stride = sizeof(T)) {
    *pp = (T*) ((char*) *pp + stride);
    // p = (void*)((char*)p + stride);
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    union{
        struct{
            char a[sizeof(int)];
            int b;
            int c;
        };
        char chars[];
    }raw = {{"ss",  22}};

    char *pchar = raw.chars;
    int *pint1 = &raw.c, *pint2 = &raw.c, *pint3 = &raw.c, *pint4 = &raw.c; 
    // a long code, or maybe define a macro
    pint1 = (int*) ((char*) pchar + sizeof(raw.a));
    pint2 = (int*) ((intptr_t) pchar + sizeof(raw.a));

    // expect a unified way
    pint3 = differby<int*, char*>(pchar, sizeof(raw.a));
    pint3 = offsetptr<int>(pchar, sizeof(raw.a));

    pint4 = (int*)pchar;
    moveptr(&pint4, sizeof(raw.a));

    cout << *pint1 << ", " << *pint2 << ", " << *pint3 << ", " << *pint4 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Issue

Is there any trick to do `int *pint3 = offsetptr(pchar, sizeof(raw.a));` without no template argument?

BTW, how to capture the result of a template argument deduction/substitution? like when gcc cannot deduce template parameter 'To', it will print `error: no matching function for call to 'convert(double&)'`

### References

- [Template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)
- [Converting Pointer Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa234627(v=vs.60).aspx)
- [type punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning)
- [Type-punning and strict-aliasing](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/06/10/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing/)

Comment: return types don't participate in template parameter deduction: http://ideone.com/x6LSF1.

Comment: Why? It's not a good design for c++ or compilers because of type-safe so as to require us to explicitly perform a type cast. However, I have a clear idea about this by writing a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template deduction for function based on its return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612961/template-deduction-for-function-based-on-its-return-type)