# need to return the same type as this from c++ template function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want a template function to return the same type as `this`. It is easy to get the types of arguments in parens, but I do not see how to get the type of the object whose method is called.

```
struct ENode {
    ENode* mnext;
    ENode(ENode* n):mnext(n){}
    template<typename T>T* next(T* unused) { return (T*)mnext; }
    template<typename T>T* xnext() { return (T*)mnext; }
};

struct TNode : public ENode {
    int val;
    TNode(int v, TNode* n):val(v),ENode(n){}
};

void printTN(TNode* n) {
    while(n) {
    printf("%i -> ", n->val);
//  n=n->next(n); // ok, but n is unused
//  n=n->xnext(); // error: template argument deduction/substitution failed:  couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
//  n=n->xnext<std::remove_reference<decltype(*n)>::type>(); // works, but is very ugly
    n=n->xnext<TNode>(); // works, but is ugly
    }
    printf("nil\n");
}
```

How do I have `n->next()` return the same type as `n`?

**EDIT**
As to
[Template deduction for function based on its return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612961/template-deduction-for-function-based-on-its-return-type) , it would help me if it was possible. But there is *no overload or type deduction* on the return type in C++ (unlike Java). Therefore I want an overload on the type of `*this`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template deduction for function based on its return type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612961/template-deduction-for-function-based-on-its-return-type)

Comment: What's the point of doing all this?

Comment: @GillBates That's not what he wants. He wants the return type to match the class of the object the method is called on, not deduce the template from the return type.

Comment: I can see `TNode` inherits from `ENode`. If you need to convert parent class to child class, use `dynamic_cast` and check for `NULL/nullptr` for safe run-time behavior. I don't see any point having templated function like you do now. It's plain ugly and illogical.

Comment: @Barmar But in the argument example he asks for `T` too. He returns `T` twice. You might be right but the situation has the same result at this moment.

Comment: @GillBates Of course, since he's returning the same type as `this`, dispatching on either type will work. But C++ doesn't allow templating on return type, but it does allow templating on parameter types, so a dup saying you can't do it is not productive.

Comment: You are adding a built-in casting-to-derived-class to a base class method, which can only be used in a context where you already know the derived class type. So, how is it any better than a performing a plain cast?

Answer (score 5):

A common pattern is to have the entire ENode class take a template parameter, instead of just the next/xnext methods.

E.g.,

```
template <typename T> struct ENode {
    ...
    T* next() { return mnext; }
};
struct TNode : ENode<TNode> { ... }
```

Comment: And the name of this pattern is ["Curiously Recurring Template Pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), CRTP for short.

Comment: @PhilM That's good, but how do I extend `TNode`? Looks like with `struct UNode : TNode<????> { ... }` next() will not return `UNode`.

Comment: True. In that case, you'd essentially have to make TNode templated, and have UNode derive from TNode the same way T does from E. Turtles all the way down.

Comment: @4294967295 Yes, "turtles all the way down" occurs very commonly with CRTP.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the slight change in syntax, one possibility is to make `next` a free function template:

```
struct ENode {
    ENode* mnext;
    ENode(ENode* n):mnext(n){}
    template<typename T> friend T* next(T *self) { return static_cast<T*>(self->mnext); }
};

struct TNode : public ENode {
    int val;
    TNode(int v, TNode* n):val(v),ENode(n){}
};

void printTN(TNode* n) {
    while(n) {
      printf("%i -> ", n->val);
      n = next(n);
    }
    printf("nil\n");
}
```