# How to properly perform operations on two templates of the same type?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++17

I am getting the following error from the compiler: `error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'Expected<double>' and 'Expected<double>')` Expected is either a type, or an exception.

```
template<typename T>
class Expected
{
    template<typename U>
    Expected<U> apply(std::function<U(T)> f)
    {
        if(!valid) return std::get<std::exception_ptr>(state);
        try
        {
            return f(std::get<T>(state));
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            return std::current_exception();
        }
    }
};   


#define MixedMode(op)\
template<typename T, typename U, typename V>\
Expected<U> op(Expected<T> t, Expected<V> v)\
{\
    return t.apply([&](T myT){return op(v,myT);});\
}\
template<typename T, typename U, typename V>\
Expected<U> op(Expected<T> t, V v)\
{\
    return t.apply([&](T myT){return op(myT,v);});\
}\
\
template<typename T, typename U, typename V>\
Expected<U> op(V v, Expected<T> t)\
{\
    return t.apply([&](T myT){return op(v,myT);});\
}\


MixedMode(operator+)

int main()
{
    Expected<double> a;
    Expected<double> b;

    a + b;
}
```

I believe in my header file I have done enough to get them to overload and  add them together. In the first I am expecting two templates to add together. In my main file, I simply call:

```
Expected<double> a;
Expected<double> b;
std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
```

And then the error is thrown. Before I added `Expected<U> op(Expected<T> t, Expected<V> v)\` portion of the code, I was able to compile and run if I had a function called `operator T() { return value(); }` which would implicitly cast the `Expected<T>` to whatever type was being passed in. However, I realized that my `apply` function was never being used. Not only that, when I check the Type of `a+b` I was returned a `double` instead of an `Expected<double>` so I eliminated the `operator T()` function and the compiler informed me that it doesn't know how to add two `Expected<T>` together.

How do I go about fixing this error? I have been beating my head against this all day.

Comment: Could you beat that into a [mcve], please? For example, it probably doesn't work without the macro, you don't need all of the chaff inside the class. You can probably [beat it down to this](https://ideone.com/cNcRpF) and still get the same error. Why experiment with all that extra noise?

Comment: @user4581301 I can try to beat it into a minimal example I was going to exclude `operator<<` then I realized I needed it so no one would have to write it themselves. Can I just use yours?

Comment: @user4581301 I also have the macro because I am going to be using all the operators except for `+=,-=, =` etc. So I figured I should just leave it how it is for now.

Comment: Be my guest, but I suggest playing  with what I did a bit first to make sure it really is the same error you're getting.

Comment: @user4581301 it is the same error that I have been getting. I just shortened what the error said because it was rather long and filled up my entire console.

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more, `U` is dependent on the return type, [and this is a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612961/template-deduction-for-function-based-on-its-return-type). How does the template know what the return type is going to be?

Comment: @user4581301 I don't think that is possible with templates. Especially in this case where the return type is either a data type, or an exception.

Comment: I know it's not possible. Why return an exception rather than catching it at a lower level anyway?

Comment: @user4581301 I basically am trying to implement a monad in C++. Theoretically I should be able to do something like `Expected<std::exception> a; Expected<double> b; a + b;` and it should execute that piece of code until I ask for the value in a cout statement. Where then the exception will be returned to me.

Comment: Cool. I figured there'd be a good story behind that decision. But this wraps us back around to you can't deduce `U`, making the return type of `Expected<U>` impossible. You will have to find another way, and it seems I'm too stupid at the moment to provide it.

Comment: [This compiles](http://rextester.com/ELZ70449)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bodies of template functions are never used to deduce template parameters.  `U` cannot be deduced from the arguments, so your `+` overloads are ignored.

```
#define MixedMode(op)\
template<typename T, typename V>\
auto op(Expected<T> t, Expected<V> v)\
{\
  return t.apply([&](T myT){return op(v,myT);});\
}\
template<typename T, typename V>\
auto op(Expected<T> t, V v)\
{\
  return t.apply([&](T myT){return op(myT,v);});\
}\
template<typename T, typename V>\
auto op(V v, Expected<T> t)\
{\
  return t.apply([&](T myT){return op(v,myT);});\
}
```

This will fail to compile, but that is because you wrote `apply` wrong.

A `std::function` is not a lambda, and a lambda is not a `std::function`.  If you are deducing the type of a `std::function` 999/1000 times you are screwing up, brcause `std::function` is about type erasure and deduction is about type deduction, and *those are opposite concepts*.

More importantly, you are composing them backwards, and they don't compose that way.

```
template<class F>
Expected<std::invoke_result_t<F&,T&>> apply(F f){
```

or something similar.

Comment: Sorry, it is taking me sometime to wrap my head around your answer. But I'm still not sure how apply is written incorrectly. If the result is not an exception, try doing the operation what I am assuming is `Expected<double> + Expected<double>` and return the result of that. Catch the exception if there are any. 

I also have never seen `std::invoke_result_t` would you care to explain how this works? And lastly, if apply is correctly done, will the rest of the compiler errors go away?

Comment: I gave corrected code.  What is unclear about it?  I gave a fix for apply.  I fixed whatever errors I could spot. Your question lacks a [mcve] so I do not know what other errors there are, nor did I test my code on an online compiler so I could have typos.  Did you try googling `std::invoke_result` and reading say [this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of)?  If you have new questions after reading about it, asking them via the "ask a question" button or searching SO is a good plan; comments are too brief.